# For creating a bootable USB stick if your machine has plenty of storage space on its disk do you still have to partition Windows

Tags: dual-boot, live-usb

I only ask because of this guide I'm following, but I still plan on using Windows on my machine and I don't like the idea of partitioning it.

https://www.lifewire.com/ultimate-windows-7-ubuntu-linux-dual-boot-guide-2200653

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got a wrong idea, I suppose. 
Partitioning the disk won't remove windows.

For example-
Let's say that you have a 500gb hard disk with windows on it. 
The drive is partitioned(grouped) into many parts. You have the OS in C:\, etc.
Now you partition your drive again. This means that you allocate a fixed amount of free space for a purpose(Installing Linux here).

The bootable drive is just a pen drive that helps you to boot the installer and install it into the free space(partition)allocated for Linux. 
The bootable drive and the partitioning are not related at all.

The following video might help-
https://youtu.be/HpUgIkl4oFA